# Real world practical Outliers/Anomalies

Tags: outliers, anomaly-detection, real-time, example

I want to have some real life and practical examples for anomalies that can be expressed like a scenario.

For example in a country following left-hand driving, a vehicle moving in a wrong direction will be an anomaly.

Seeking for examples like this or other descriptions under the definition of anomaly.

Comment: Your question is too vague, and the context is not clear. For instance, if you're studying traffic accidents then you can't label the driver in your example as an outlier. The outlier designation means a special treatment, such as removal from the data set. The wrong side drivers are expected to occur in traffic incident databases, in this context they're not an anomaly.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Maybe it is because I usually think of outliers as outlying wrt to a *model* so they are not an intrinsic features of the *data*. For example, a right hand driving driver would be an outliers wrt to *some* model of what driving looks like in left hand side driving countries but not against all such models. The interesting story in this framework would be how a certain model (linear regression say) goes astray when presented with some form of inputs.

Comment: @user603 I've just given an example to illustrate, whereas I'm not specifically working in traffic databases. Can you add some more examples other than mine in a more sophisticated way, same for Mr. Aksakal too...

Comment: @Aksakal I'm studying bibliographic information networks in which the objects are _authors_, _co-authors_, _papers_ and _venues_ among which I'm targeting _authors_

Comment: The problem is that you define a scenario, it often is too common. For example, you may consider any author that only published once to be an outlier (in some sense, he is "outside" the community). But there are probably millions of such authors.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I need examples from real world other than this...